# Regex to extract certain information until a specific word appears

Tags: python, regex

```
Plan Savings Budget 20000 Account Personal Dividend Minimum Amount abcd123 Plan Current Budget 1000 Account Joint Dividend Maximum Amount abcd123
```

Here the content I have to extract is savings, 20000, personal and minimum amount.

```
Plan (.*?) Budget (.*?) Account (.*?) Dividend (.*?)
```

This does not give me Minimum Amount.

```
Expected output: [['Savings', '20000', 'Personal', 'Minimum Amount'],['Current','1000','Joint','Maximum Amount']
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What code have you written, and what output would you expect from it?

Comment: I guess all you need is to append "abcd123" to your regex, see https://regex101.com/r/Zw0XA9/1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `re.findall` as follows;

```
re.findall('(Savings|Current| \d+ |Personal|Joint|Maximum Amount|Minimum Amount)', y, re.I)
```

Where `y` is the string you want to search for that pattern.
Here is the result that I get.

```
>>>  ['Savings',' 20000 ','Personal','Minimum Amount','Current',' 1000 ','Joint','Maximum Amount']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of "split" strings and loop and do your regex:

```
input = "Plan Savings Budget 20000 Account Personal Dividend Minimum Amount abcd123 Plan Current Budget 1000 Account Joint Dividend Maximum Amount abcd123"

theList = input.split("abcd123")
for item in theList:
  # Do your regex processing here
```